# Segue from a static and manually placed UITableViewCell to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

[image]

**Steps**

1. I've manually placed a UITableViewCell into a UIViewController.
2. Dragged and Dropped a segue from the UITableViewCell to adjacent UIViewController

As you can see from the screenshot the segue has been created

**Issue:** Segue is not occuring.

I do see the tap effect (gray background) on the UITableViewCell in the simulator.

Comment: So you are using `UITableViewCell` without `UITableView`?

Comment: yes `UITableViewCell` (standalone) on it's own, no `UITableView`

Comment: What you are actually trying to achieve with that?

Comment: I want it to act as a button and segue to the adjacent `UIViewController`

Comment: Then why don't you directly use `UIButton`?

Comment: I like the disclosure indicator next to it and that's the design, you mean `UITableView` cell won't work

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use `UITableViewCell` that way

Comment: it will take one minute to add a stackview with an UIButton and an UIImageview/UIButton for your arrow. Then you can reuse that Stackview again.

Comment: so the UITableViewCell doesn't work? I wonder why was I even able to drag and drop a segue from UITableViewCell in XCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by placing a UITableView within the VC and then created a segue from there.